# Telling python that a next line is part of variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this variable

```
x = (df['DateMask1'] == 'Date') & (df['DateMask2'] == 'Date') & (df['Date1'] > df['Date2'])
```

How can i say that the second line is part of the variable "x" to python?

```
x = (df['DateMask1'] == 'Date') & (df['DateMask2'] == 'Date')
    & (df['Date1'] > df['Date2'])
```

Comment: Add \ at the end of the first line.